# update from text type field to term reference

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Using Drupal 7 I have already created and populated a contenty type. I want to use the already info I have already setup for one of the fields in this content type as a ter mreference, pointing to the Taxonomy I have just created (ex: previous text type field 'banana' has to be converted to field type 'term referece' from 'Fruits' taxonomy, picking up 'banana' as it value).

This way would avoid removing previous nodes and reinserting again (it's the same info but pointing to a new field type ('term reference').

Is that possible?

thanks

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to achieve here, could you reformulate and clarify?

Comment: Convert a text type field to term reference without having to change field type and as consequence reinsert all the info